# The program does not contain a static main method suitable as an entry point

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, type-conversion, program-entry-point

Hi guys I am a beginner,

I am trying to create a function to convert a string to an integer and an integer to a string, how can I do? As soon as I run the program I get the following error "The program does not contain a static main method suitable as an entry point "how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise
{

    static class Program
    {

        public static int Conversion(int num1, int num2)
        {
            
            num1 = 999; 
            num2 = 123;
        
            int number = Convert.ToInt32("999");
            int number2 = Convert.ToInt32("123");

            return number + number2;

        }
            static public int Main(int number, int number2) {


                Conversion(number, number2);

                Console.WriteLine(number + " and " + number2);

                return number + number2;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Main` must have either be parameterless, or have a single parameter of type `string[]`. You cannot change its signature to `(int, int)`, you must parse those CLI arguments from the passed `string[]` if you want to use them in your application.

Comment: @404: _"Why is this closed for not being reproducable or a typo?"_ because failing to declare the `Main()` method correctly, or failing to configure the project properly to use the `Main()` method, both fall squarely in the category of "typo" as it's used on this site.

Answer (score -3):

C# requires you to have a `public static int Main` method that takes no parameters or a `string[]`.

Changing your code to something like this will work:

```
static public int Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = int.Parse(args[0]);
    int number2= int.Parse(args[1]);

    Conversion(number, number2);

    Console.WriteLine(number + " and " + number2);

    return number + number2;
}
```

You now have a valid Main signature and you parse the arguments passed on the command line and assume they are integers. This will of course fail if you pass in something else (like a string) so you should add error handling but this shows the idea.

You can then start your new program like this:

```
dotnet run -- 3 5
```

Comment: Don't forget to check args length and prefer TryParse or any validation process.